# "Being wasted" or "Getting wasted" What's the difference?

Tags: difference

1. Time is being wasted
2. Time is getting wasted

Which is correct one? Which should I use? Which sounds good?

Comment: Before I read your sentences and only saw the title, I thought you were talking about marijuana. To be wasted and getting wasted mean to get high. Time is being wasted. Remember that get means **become** in uses like this. He got rich. But you would not say: Time is becoming wasted.

Comment: See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27re+wasting+time%2CTime%27s+wasting%2CTime%27s+being+wasted%2CTime%27s+getting+wasted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20%27re%20wasting%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTime%20%27s%20wasting%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...and [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We+are+wasting+time%2CTime+is+wasting%2CTime+is+being+wasted%2CTime+is+getting+wasted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20are%20wasting%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTime%20is%20wasting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTime%20is%20being%20wasted%3B%2Cc0), showing that (with or without contractions), we're much more likely to include the relevant subject - where ***We're wasting time*** is already more common than all your alternatives, not to mention ***You're / He's / I'm** wasting time*, etc.

Answer (score 4):

*Time's getting wasted* is not idiomatic. I think most people would say *We/you are wasting time*, or, if you don't want to lay the blame on anyone, *Time is being wasted.*

Answer (score -1):

Out of the two, *Time is being wasted* is better, but I would say this instead:

*"Time's wasting."*

Comment: Not in my experience.

Comment: Old-fashioned but still used: Time's a-wasting.